# Code to compare each cell in a column to every cell in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns with random times and the times come from two different sources so the columns do not have the same amount of data points.  I want to start with the first time in the first column and compare it to each time in the second column.  If there is a match in times, I would like to pull relevant data. After a match is found (if there is one) I would like for the code to go to the second cell in the first column and compare it to every value in the second column and so on.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub TransferInfo()

'Activate the Sub to Convert and Format Dates
Call ConvertDates

'Define Variables
Dim st As Worksheet
Dim ts As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
j = 2

'Find and set the last used row
Set st = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Table")
lastrow = st.Cells(st.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set ts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ShopFloor")

'Cycle through/compare Row J, Column 18 based on each cell in Row I, Column 14
For i = 2 To lastrow
    Do Until IsEmpty(ts.Cells(j, 8)) Or IsEmpty(st.Cells(j, 2))
        If st.Cells(i, 14).Value = ts.Cells(j, 18).Value Then  
    st.Cells(i, 15).Value = ts.Cells(j, 2).Value
    Exit Do
    Else
    st.Cells(i, 15).Value = ""
    End If
    j = j + 1
  Loop
j = 2
Next i

End Sub
```

The other sub that I call at the beginning of this sub simply rounds the times in each column to the nearest 15 minute interval to increase the likelihood of matches between the columns.

My question is: The code does not copy and paste any more information although there are times that match between the two columns.  Why would the code that I have not work?  Also, with larger data sets I am afraid that this the code may crash Excel and because I have a loop within a loop trying to process a lot of data a lot of times, but I don't know of a more efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to without this code.

If anyone has any insights as to why this code doesn't work I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with a `=MATCH()` formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you just need an INDEX/MATCH formula. Use this in O2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(N2,R:R,0)),"")
```

No need for VBA

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and I haven't used the match function before but I will look into it.  But in my case, I would insert your formula into column D and, for example, if A1 matched with B25, I would need to pull C25 into D1

Comment: Macro Man, thank you for your answer, I used a version of it to find my solution.  Originally I was just caught up in the idea that VBA would be more efficient.  Thanks again!